# preg_replace doesn't work but worked before

Tags: php, preg-replace, html-entities

I'm using this to replace smilies:

```
    $msg = preg_replace('#:\)#', '<img src="img.gif" />', $msg);
```

It worked fine, before I used htmlentites:

```
    $msg = htmlentities(stripslashes($msg), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, "ISO-8859-1");
```

So, I don't know how to resolve the problem.
Thanks for help.

Comment: _patient_ Dr it hurts when I raise my arms over my head _Doctor_ Well dont raise your arms over your head then.

Comment: You don't need to use preg_replace, use str_replace. use html_entities (if needed) before the replacement (think to change the string you search for str_replace.)

Comment: html_entities were before the replacement, and I tried str_replace: $msg = str_replace(':\\)', '<img src="img.gif" />', $msg); but still doesn't work

Comment: You don't need to use a backslash when you use str_replace. The ) has no meaning so you don't have to escape it. Just do $msg = str_replace(":)", '<img src="img.gif" />', $msg);

Comment: It still doesn't work. My code is $msg = str_replace(':)', '<img src="img.gif" />', $msg); as you said, so why doesn't this work ?

Comment: Oh, by the way, nothing (str_replace or preg_replace) works now...

Comment: Nevermind, it was a problem of htmlentities.